# Reliable, free 2D dimensional drawing tool

Tags: cross-platform, drawing, cad, scalability, dimensions

So far the CAD programs I have checked don't seem to support what I am looking for - but I'd be happy to be shown wrong :)

I want to be able to create dimensioned, scalable 2D drawings - specifically for drawing patterns for furniture, clothing, gardens, and rooms.

I've looked at [FreeCAD](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/free-cad/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) so far - but neither seems to handle what I'm hoping to do. Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to find the tool I used many moons ago under Win9x: [CadStd Lite](http://www.cadstd.com/lite.php)!

Answer (score 0):

BRL-CAD is FLOSS and developed originally by the US Army. If you didn't like FreeCAD you might not go for this, though. What nonfree programs have you found that serve your purposes?

If you mean free as in beer then you might also be satisfied with Google SketchUp, but I have yet to really dig deep into it's functionality.

I'd try typing the software you would use but it is nonfree into alternativeto.com and select open source license and linux and see what it gives you.

Comment: BRL-CAD I've tried in the past - but I don't understand it at all. There was a program I used to use back in the Win9x days that was free as in beer that did 2D drawing with dimensions (great for basic plans) ... but I can't for the life of me recall what it was called (maybe cadre?). I'd even take inexpensive if it worked

Comment: That looks cool. I'll try it too. I didn't know of this one. Thanks!